# Where to download the java.util.*, java.io.* classes?

Tags: java, url, io, download

I managed to download files for a java game called "Robobmbo". But I have run into some problems.  Most of the classes have imported other classes like `java.net.URLConnection`. But I have no idea where to find these files. Can anyone tell me where I can download: `java.net.*`, `java.io.*`, etcetera. ?

The example below is from the MusicPlayer.class. Its supposed to play a module music track in the game. I am having a hard time finding this module. I believe the link to the module is in `URLConnection` or `URL`. How do I open the `URLConnection` class file?

```
package game;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import litecom.Trace;
import litecom.modplayer.Mod;
import litecom.modplayer.ModPlayer;
```

I downloaded Eclipse, opened it, then tried opening the class file but it failed. I searched the internet and found that you should go to `preference > general editor` and `Class File Editor` as the default. But there is no class editor in the list :(. What do I do?

Comment: Can you share the specific error you are having? Sounds to me like the problem is something different from what you are describing. java.io and java.util are part of the standard JVM

Comment: I think u need to include the JDK/JRE in the class path.

Comment: I feel like I could never be drunk enough to properly parse this question.

Comment: Since being bone tired is as good as drunk ;) I took a stab at rewording the question. My take: they are having some other problem (like mprivat said) and think they are missing files. So they are trying to view the *source* of java.net.URLConnection, etc.. in Eclipse from just its .class file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The io,util etc packages are part of the core Java API and should be with your JRE.

Please can you paste in the error you are getting.

-- Since your update --

The URL class is part of the Java API - i.e. when you install Java you will see it.

Try installing Java + Eclipse, then open this file in Eclipse, right click on the classes that you can't find and then select "Definition" and it will show you where they come from.

However - being kind - this is a terrible question, you have downloaded Java code and don't understand the very basics of how to compile or edit it.

Comment: Thinking about it, it looks like he might not even have a JRE installed and is just looking at the imports in the code.

Comment: .. it also sounds like you may be biting off a lot more than you can chew. If you are unfamiliar with the basics of compiling in java, you should start with something much simpler and smaller than this.

Comment: i see what u mean but im not trying to learn java.... i just want to get the url file so i can see where this game searches for the module file...

Comment: In order for anyone to help, you need to 1) post the specific errors you are receiving and 2) when they occur (during compilation, when the program executes a specific section of code, ..?)

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout How can I import an external library in my own java project. for e.g I want to load this http://www.java2html.de/download.html
I don't know where to copy the files in eclipse.